# Anybody else using PC Healthboost?

Tags: windows-7

I just downloaded and installed PC Healthboost. 
It did a scan and found some errors and clutters that slows down my computer.
Should I get the full version?

Answer (score 4):

Most (all?) such programs are scams and pure snake-oil. Best case they are placebos, worst case they will completely mess up your OS. Don't waste your money on them.

If you *must* use something purely for peace of mind, use CCleaner.

Comment: I have had trouble with CCleaner registry cleaner recently, and I realized that I didnt really need it and was doing it out of pure habit

Comment: In my testing I have found CCleaner to at least be conservative in what it cleans in the registry, but of course YMMV. Cleaning the registry in modern Windows versions doesn't provide the boost most people think it does, and if they think it helped it is often just a placebo effect.

Comment: I agree, never had a machine crash because of it, but after moving to windows 8, I didnt even bother to install ccleaner.The only thing I was using it for lately was managing startup apps and the new task manager in 8 takes care of it.