# is a "booster" software helpful?

Tags: windows-xp

I have seen some things online stating to boost performance, such as eBoostr. 
there are several programs which do basically what this one does, and they are all trial/payware. are any of those types of programs legit(i.e. at least,non-infected), and if so do they have any benefit?

I'm pretty sure those are just scams but I figured I'd ask in case I'm missing something important.

Comment: I have never in two and half decades of being online found a single program that you describe worth actually using.

Comment: The TV commercials in my area for sites like these are pretty funny. The testimonials from the "real users" are hilarious! I'm curious if anyone with technical experience has ever attempted testing one of them. Perhaps I'll toss one of them into a VM and see what it does.

Comment: @moses I agree, a VM might be a good test method.
I should probably also ask if there are any methods for improving performance. aside from clearing browser history/cache/etc. (which gets done often) and rebooting often, is there a better way?

Comment: There is not improve performane is a vague benchmark

Comment: possible duplicate of [Anybody else using PC Healthboost?](http://superuser.com/questions/620112/anybody-else-using-pc-healthboost)

Comment: @techie007 it's not an exact duplicate but admittedly it deals with a similar topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't say that all performance tools are useless. The field of operation is far too varied and way too complex to generalize:

I'm using Memory Zipper Plus which is an old memory optimization tool that helps freeing up memory that has been allocated but lost due to memory leaks or just isn't in use. Since I'm running my system without a swap file, I can clearly see a difference. Applications that complain about not being able to run because of a lack of free memory can do so after running the tool. It can't do magic though. If there's not enough memory to free up, then it also can't help.

Another tool that does a similar thing for Firefox is Firemin. It uses part of the Windows Api (EmptyWorkingSet) to flush allocated but unused memory by the browser. It limits itself to Firefox though. There are other tools that use the very same api call to flush all process running and they also actually work nicely.

You can boost your performance by properly using a defragmentation tool (if you don't use SSDs). This can have a measurable impact on basically all of the system performance, especially if it supports defragmenting the MFT.

There are tools that allow for compressing the registry. This is especially useful for systems that have seen a massive amount of programs. Once the registry grows, it doesn't shrink back. Also, it can be fragmented in itself.

In case of eboostr I wouldn't put too much hope into it helping you out. The website is rather vague with what kind of features it supports. It does sound like they're selling snake oil as someone here already has put it.

If you don't know that your computer is actually underperforming and in which regard, then I wouldn't actually just run a random booster on it. Chances are you end up with ad/malware or the program screwing up the system or it might be slower than before. Rather try to figure out what needs fixing and look for a specific tool for that problem. If you can't make one out, then your system is fine. Correct me if I'm wrong, but there's probably no single tool that allows you to fix, optimize and speed up a whole operating system in every possible way.

Comment: I usually avoid running random software. I figured I'd get better advice here and I did, so thank you :)
I would be wary if a tool offered to fix everything, I had just hoped there was something that could make it a little better.
(just a note, the thing with "emptyworkingset" I heard that it can actually reduce performance, but that might be only if it affects everything. I'll look into the firefox plugin you mentioned)

Comment: You're welcome. Since I optimize my systems in every possible way, I might be able to give you a better lead on what you could try if you told me what exactly you think is bogging your system down. Is it the hard drive? Defragmenting and disabling the swap file can help. So can disabling superfetch, windows search indexer, uninstalling AV software, automatic defrag software etc. You can disable unused services or lite your operating system with nlite. A re-install can also help wonders. Furthermore you can overclock CPU, the system bus and/or RAM. There are countless ways to improve a system.

Comment: system's a DELL, so I can't overclock the CPU and RAM. I am sort of tight on cash or else I would've bought a new one or at least more ram. it's volume activated so I don't think I can reinstall without giving me a lot of trouble. I use AVAST since it seems to keep quiet compared to MSSE or Norton since those ones are CPU hogs even when there's not much to do. 
I'll look into ending Superfetch, and look at nlite. thanks for the tips!

Comment: Superfetch was only introduced in Vista, so this hint doesn't apply to you. Any kind of antivirus tool with real time protection slows down the system more or less. However, it would be bad advice to suggest disabling it if you don't feel safe without it. Nlite can help you to get rid of uninstallable Windows components. You'll need to re-install the system for this to take effect, but this can really speed things up. There are also tools to shorten or eliminate the delay of menu popups. I remember using one years ago for XP. It doesn't speed up the operating system, but rather your workflow.

Answer (score 5):

All of the applications are snake oil.  They typically dont do anything useful and some are even detrimental.  A few things they do that are useful can be easily done by the user.  These companies prey on the computer illiterate to make money.

Check out these well written articles:

- http://www.howtogeek.com/171734/benchmarked-will-a-game-booster-improve-your-pc-gaming-performance/
- http://www.howtogeek.com/162683/pc-cleaning-apps-are-a-scam-heres-why-and-how-to-speed-up-your-pc/
- http://www.howtogeek.com/171633/why-using-a-registry-cleaner-wont-speed-up-your-pc-or-fix-crashes/
- http://www.howtogeek.com/171424/why-memory-optimizers-and-ram-boosters-are-worse-than-useless/
- http://www.howtogeek.com/171816/htg-explains-do-you-need-to-use-a-driver-cleaner-when-upgrading-hardware-drivers/

Comment: I see. basically these links says to do nothing, and it'll be ok?

Comment: why do you think you need them?

Comment: I wanted to find something to help my PC perform a little better before I can upgrade it. I won't need to do that as much in the future, but for now I have to deal with the computer I have and wanted to squeeze every bit out of it.

Comment: These programs arent worth it.  The best thing IMO is a clean install of Windows, patched to to current, the latest drivers from the hardware manufacturer, and installing only reliable software.

Answer (score 0):

The only legitimate "booster" I've come across is [Opera's "turbo mode"](http://www.opera.com/turbo) which routes network traffic through their proxy server and highly compresses it.

If you'd like a real performance boost, you could install *basically any* Linux distro. Particularly one that uses a lightweight **Desktop Environment** and/or **Window Manager**. Good examples include: [ArchBang](http://archbang.org) ([OpenBox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Openbox)), [Puppy Linux](https://puppylinux.org) ([JWM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jwm)), and [TinyCore](http://tinycorelinux.net) ([FLWM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLWM)).

Comment: And turbo mode is just a proxy that compresses stuff.

Comment: I am considering installing Linux, however a few applications will not run or will not work efficiently on Linux.
graphics drivers for my are also typically only semi-functional.